# Chapter style with horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: chapters

I am trying to create a specific chapter style for a thesis but do not have the latex know how to create it myself. The style I am going for looks like the image below. I am just trying to replicate the chapter heading itself. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a first trial, not perfect.

The `chapter` heading is typeset within `\@makechapterhead` -- Instead of the standard code, a table can be inserted there, which does the lines 'automatically'

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
      \begin{tabular}{p{1.2cm}|C{0.6\textwidth}}
        & \tabularnewline
        & \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter \tabularnewline
        & \tabularnewline
        \hline
        & \tabularnewline
        & \huge \bfseries #1 \tabularnewline
        & \tabularnewline
        \end{tabular}
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\blindtext
\chapter{A really long chapter title which wraps around}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The spacings are hard-coded of course so far, since there wasn't much time to provide an answer, and it does not work for the `chapter*` command, since this macro uses `\@makeschapterhead`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The only changes I think I need to make are aligning the vertical line with the first word of the indented paragraph and to vertically centre the entire chapter. I reckon I can do those though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `p{\parindent}` instead of `p{1.2cm}` in my code